# SQL server query to get rows as columns but keeping the columns as is

Tags: transpose

I have a table which contains data as shown below.

```
**FieldID   DocumentID  ClassID PreValue    PreScore    PreStatus   PostValue   PostScore   PostValueChanged**

1   123 1   John    80.00   Y   John    80.00   N

2   123 1   123456  71.23   N   1234    0.00    Y

1   124 2   Tom 95.65   Y   Tom 95.65   N

2   124 2   5689    53.26   N   5689    53.26   Y
```

Could someone please help with a SQL to get data in following fashion:-

```
**DocumentID    ClassID 1-PreValue  1-PreScore  1-PreStatus 1-PostValue 1-PostScore 1-PostValueChanged  2-PreValue  2-PreScore  2-PreStatus 2-PostValue 2-PostScore 2-PostValueChanged**

123 1   John    80  Y   John    80  N   123456  71.23   N   1234    0   Y

124 2   Tom 95.65   Y   Tom 95.65   N   5689    53.26   N   5689    53.26   Y
```

I tried using the Pivot Clause but couldn't get it. Please help.

----Update

I was able to achieve this for PreValue column... but couldn't make it for rest of the 5 columns... so struggling with how to concatenate rest 10 colmns i.e. 2*5.
 Here's the snippet..

```
Declare @colPivot varchar(Max)
Select @colPivot = STUFF((Select Distinct TOP 100 Percent ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),RTRIM(LTRIM(t2.FieldID))) + 'PreValue')
                From [dbo].[tbldocument] as t2 Inner join [dbo].[tbldocument] as t3 on t3.DocumentID=t2.DocumentID 
                where t2.BatchClassID=t3.BatchClassID
                Order by ',' + quotename(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255),RTRIM(LTRIM(t2.FieldID))) + 'PreValue')
                For xml path(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'')

Print @colPivot

Declare @query varchar(Max)

Set @query = 'Select * From (Select

                            [DocumentID],
                            [ClassID],
                            [PreValue],
                            convert(varchar(255),[FieldID]) + ''PreValue'' as Fieldwise

                            From 
                                [TestDB].[dbo].[tbldocument]
                            )A
            Pivot(max([PreValue]) For Fieldwise  IN ('+ @colPivot +'))p'

PRINT (@query)
Exec (@query)
```

**is it possible to create a view from above code as is?**

thanks,
Inder